# Beta Testing in Windows Dev Center

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-store, appx, windows-dev-center

I'm very, very new to Windows Dev Center, and I'm hoping someone will be able to clear some things up for me. There is an app already within the Store and I want to submit a new version of the app after beta testing. From what I have researched, you can add another submission to the app, and publish it to the store. Then when it's in the store, I'm able to define the visibility of the app. This [link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/10/managing-hidden-apps-beta-apps-and-visibility-of-in-app-purchases-in-dev-center/) is where I get this information. But, if I do this, does this mean that the previous submission is now null and void and can't be found? I think that would be the case? Is there no way to beta test the new version of the app without taking the current version out of the store? Is it recommended to upload a new app named "Blah Blah Beta" and then create a new submission on the original app after the beta gets the okay?

I'm used to iTunes connect and how they do the beta testing, so I'm not sure of the proper protocol in the Windows Dev Center. iTunes Connect you're able to have the current version in the app store, and upload new builds that can be tested.

I hope someone can clarify this for me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look at microsoft's hockey app for beta testing. There is a free level you can use.